# getting current position an ImageView

Tags: android

I created a view from ImageView. this imageview is a ball on screen(Depending on the acceleration sensor). now how can i do getting current positon it on the screen ?because I don't want the ball be out of the screen. like :

[image]

All my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;

    AnimatedView animatedView = null;
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
        setContentView(animatedView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            x -= ((int) event.values[0])*4;
            y += ((int) event.values[1])*4;

        }
    }

    public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {

        static final int width = 100;
        static final int height = 100;

        public AnimatedView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23);
            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

other question, 
Which one is better to use?TYPE_ACCELEROMETER or TYPE_GRAVITY?

I want to support more devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the position, which is your x and y.

What you need to do is to stop these values from falling of the screen.

First, get the size of your screen:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

now size holds the screenSize.

Then add the following to your method

```
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

           x -= ((int) event.values[0])*4;
           y += ((int) event.values[1])*4;
           if(x < 0)
               x = 0;
           else if(x > size.x)
               x = size.x
           if(y < 0)
               y = 0;
           else if (y > size.y)
               y = size.y

    }
```

I would also recomend that you use a thread to handle the x and y position. You can control how often a thread will run, the sensor will trigger every time an event happens.

For a better understanding of the Android Sensors, read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729759/Android-Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial
Some sensors are hardware sensors, others are software sensors that combine hardware sensors.

In your case: Im not sure what the purpose of your app is, but I guess that you want to move the ball by tilting the screen. I would say that GRAVITY works perfectly for that.

Comment: Don't forget taking into account the size of the object, width and height should be divided by 2. Otherwise it will still fall outside of the screen partially.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the location of a view by calling the `getTop()` and `getLeft()` functions which return x and y coordinates respectively, reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Position

Choosing the type depends on the goal offcourse, using Acceleromtere means measuring the acceleration of the device whilst gravity measures the gravitational force on the device.
Please note that acceleromter values include gravity values as mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

I personally would suggest using Accelerometer or the Gyroscope. The gyroscope doesn't use acceleration but the actual orientation of the device in space, which might be what you are actually looking for.